# Rails - creating object using nested restful routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

@shift_requirement belongs_to @reckoner - and in my routes

```
resources :reckoners do
  resources :shift_requirements
end
```

In /reckoners/show.html.erb I have

```
<%= link_to 'Add a shift', [:new, @reckoner, @shift_requirement] %>
```

... but I'm getting a new @reckoner rather than the new @shift_requirement that I want - where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have:

```
<%= link_to 'Add a shift', [:new, @reckoner, :shift_requirement] %>
```

Comment: Yep that does it thanks. Why is this different to the documentation though? Is it because it's a new object? [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: @RADan actually yes, it's because you link to new `shift_requirement` page, so you don't have `shift_requirement` object yet here.